# Margin bottom bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make ma text2 to have a margin from the bottom of 48px m-5 but i can't.

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-12  ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <p>text1</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 " >
              <p>text2</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: And why can't you?

Comment: Give a better explanation of your situation, if you use `mb-5` class like: `<p class="mb-5">text2</p>` do not work for you? what is the issue?

Comment: it should wotk with mb-5, https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vvLLop

Comment: I want that row to appear at the bottom of the bottom of the page wiith 48px from the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried just using the style attribute?

```
style="margin-bottom: 48px;"
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a row at the bottom of the page or at the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: I'm trying to create a row at the bottom of the viewport